Quicker way to get to $\sin^n(\theta)$?
Using a similar method to the one I use below, I found it pretty straightforward to show that $$\cos^n (\theta) = 2^{-n} \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} \cos \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\}$$ for any $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$ and any $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, and where $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!\ r!}$. This Desmos graph seems to confirm that the above equation holds.
For some reason, it doesn't seem to be as easy to find a similar formula for $\sin^n (\theta)$.
My Attempt
Let $z \in \Bbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$, and let $\theta = \mathrm{arg}(z)$.
By De Moivre's theorem, for any $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ $$z^n -z^{-n} = 2i\ \sin(n\theta)$$
From the case of n=1: $$2i\ \sin(\theta) = z - z^{-1}
\implies (2i)^n\ \sin^n(\theta) = \left(z - z^{-1} \right)^n$$
Applying binomial expansion,
$$(2i)^n\ \sin^n(\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} z^{n-r} \left(-z^{-1}\right)^{r}\right\} = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r z^{n-2r} \right\} \label{a}\tag{1}$$
The sum can be re-indexed using $k=n-r$. This allows us to sum the same things in the reverse order.
$$(2i)^n \sin^n (\theta) = \sum_{k=n}^{k=0} \left\{ \binom{n}{n-k} (-1)^{n-k} z^{2k-n} \right\} = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k (-1)^n z^{-(n-2k)} \right\} \label{b}\tag{2}$$
Note that $(-1)^{n-k} = (-1)^n (-1)^{-k} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\pm 1} = \pm 1 (-1)^n = (-1)^k (-1)^n$.
And $\binom{n}{n-k} = \binom{n}{k}$ follows from the definition of 'n choose r'.
From $\ref{a} + \ref{b}$: (recognize that $r$ and $k$ are just dummy variables, so the sums can be combined)
$$2(2i)^n \sin^n(\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \left[ z^{n-2r} + (-1)^n z^{-(n-2r)}\right] \right\}$$
Now it seems to me we need to consider the 4 possible cases for $i^n$ and $(-1)^n$ separately.
Case I: $n=4m, m \in \Bbb{Z^+}$.
In this case $i^n = 1$ and $(-1)^n = 1$. So we get: $$2^{n+1} \sin^n(\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \left[ z^{n-2r} + z^{-(n-2r)}\right] \right\} = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r 2\cos \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\}$$
Note that it is also as a consequence of De Moivre's Theorem that $z^n + z^{-n} = 2 \cos(n\theta)$.
$$ \therefore \sin^n(\theta) = 2^{-n} \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \cos \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\}$$
Case II: $n=4m-1$.
In this case, $i^n = -i$ and $(-1)^n = -1$. So: $$-2^{n+1} i \sin^n(\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \left[ z^{n-2r} - z^{-(n-2r)}\right] \right\} = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r 2i \sin \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\}$$
$$ \therefore \sin^n(\theta) = -2^{-n}\sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \sin \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\} $$
Case III: $n=4m-2$.
$i^n = -1$ and $(-1)^n = 1$. $$\implies -2^{n+1} \sin^n(\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \left[ z^{n-2r} + z^{-(n-2r)}\right] \right\} = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r 2 \cos \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\}$$
$$ \therefore \sin^n(\theta) = -2^{-n}\sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \cos \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\} $$
Case IV $n=4m-3$.
$i^n = i$ and $(-1)^n = -1$. $$\implies 2^{n+1} i \sin^n(\theta) = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \left[ z^{n-2r} - z^{-(n-2r)}\right] \right\} = \sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r 2i \sin \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\}$$
$$ \therefore \sin^n(\theta) = 2^{-n}\sum_{r=0}^{r=n} \left\{ \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \sin \left( [n-2r] \theta \right) \right\} $$
This other Desmos graph seems to suggest that these equations are working well.
I'm just wondering whether there's another, simpler equation for $\sin^n(\theta)$, and if there's a quicker way to get there!

See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html


You are dealing with (finite) Fourier series. 2) See the general formula given in this answer.


For all $n \in \mathbb {N}$,
$
\begin{align}
{\sin}^{2 n} \left( \theta \right)
& = {\left( \frac {{e}^{i \theta} - {e}^{- i \theta}}{2 i} \right)}^{2 n} \\
& = \frac {1}{{\left( 2 i \right)}^{2 n}} {\left( {e}^{i \theta} \right)}^{2 n} {\left( 1 - {e}^{- 2 i \theta} \right)}^{2 n} \\
& = \frac {1}{{\left( 2 i \right)}^{2 n}} {\left( {e}^{i \theta} \right)}^{2 n}  \sum_{k = 0}^{2 n} \binom {2 n}{k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} {\left( {e}^{- 2 i \theta} \right)}^{k} \\
& = \frac {1}{{4}^{n}} \sum_{k = 0}^{2 n} \binom {2 n}{k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{n - k} {e}^{\left( 2 n - 2 k \right) i \theta} \\
& = \frac {1}{{4}^{n}} \Bigg[ \binom {2 n}{n} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \binom {2 n}{k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{n - k} {e}^{\left( 2 n - 2 k \right) i \theta} + \sum_{k = n + 1}^{2 n} \binom {2 n}{k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{n - k} {e}^{\left( 2 n - 2 k \right) i \theta} \Bigg] \\
& = \frac {1}{{4}^{n}} \Bigg[ \binom {2 n}{n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \binom {2 n}{n - k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} {e}^{2 k i \theta} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \binom {2 n}{n + k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} {e}^{- 2 k i \theta} \Bigg] \\
& = \frac {1}{{4}^{n}} \Bigg[ \binom {2 n}{n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \binom {2 n}{n - k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} \left( {e}^{2 i k \theta} + {e}^{- 2 i k \theta} \right) \Bigg] \\
& = \frac {1}{{4}^{n}} \Bigg[ \binom {2 n}{n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \binom {2 n}{n - k} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} \, 2 \cos \left( 2 k \theta \right) \Bigg]. \\
\end{align}
$
The case where the power is odd can be derived similarly.
